# How do I load a gradle java project into Intellij with bad gradle code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

When I try to open a new java project into IntelliJ there are problems running the gradle build and the project won't load. It doesn't even create an .idea folder.

This means I can't edit anything in my IDE to fix the errors.

Is there a way to just load it into IntelliJ and have it ignore the gradle stuff?

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5
Build #IC-162.2228.15, built on October 14, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_102-b14 amd64
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
```

Comment: You can just import it as simple java project, whenever it will ask you about gradle support you decline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your project, delete `.ipr`, `.iml`, `.iws` files and `.idea` dir.

In IntelliJ  `File > New > Project From Existing Sources...`

Select `Create project from existing sources`, not import.

Next, next, next

Then is going to say `Unlinked Gradle project?` - decline.

Fix your stuff and run it in terminal `alt+f12` then if it's fine you can link the project back to IntelliJ.

Also check **Build, execution, Deployment** in IntelliJ settings

Comment: Which support is this that needs turning back on and how is that done?

Comment: I meant link the project again, i will edit the answer